# Autoformatting same function with different parameters

Tags: formatting, format, autoformatting

Are there any ways to configure autoformatting of code to display the same function with different parameters in a grid pattern?
I am looking for examples in any environment (preferably vscode), because I couldn't find any examples anywhere.
The following is a simple example:

```
function('asd',     'asd',    2,      'asd')
function('asddawe', 'asdfe',  42,     '')
function('',        'asd',    0,      'asd')
function('asd',     'asd',    513531, 'asd')
```